# Converting tables in .dat file to HTML tables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have one .dat file and it includes the below tables:

```
06:53:39     CPU   %user   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal   %idle    intr/s
06:53:40     all    1.68    0.00    1.85    0.84    0.00    0.17    0.00   95.46   1335.64
06:53:40       0    2.97    0.00    0.99    2.97    0.00    0.99    0.00   92.08   1069.31
06:53:40       1    1.01    0.00    1.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.98      0.00


06:53:40     CPU   %user   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal   %idle    intr/s
06:53:41     all    0.34    0.00    0.34    0.17    0.17    0.17    0.00   98.83   1145.00
06:53:41       0    0.00    0.00    1.00    2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.00   1035.00
06:53:41       1    1.00    0.00    2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.00      0.00


Average:     CPU   %user   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal   %idle    intr/s
Average:     all    1.01    0.00    1.09    0.50    0.08    0.17    0.00   97.15   1240.80
Average:       0    1.49    0.00    1.00    2.49    0.00    0.50    0.00   94.53   1052.24
Average:       1    1.01    0.00    1.51    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   97.49      0.00
```

I'm trying to convert this into HTML table using the below code:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n <html>\n <Body>\n<table>"
    } 
    {print "<tr>"
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        print "<td>" $i"</td>"
    print "</tr>"
    }
END{
    print "\n</Body>\n</html>\n</table>"
    }' file.dat >> file.html
```

This particular code treating as one complete HTML table and add all the records. As you can see in the .dat file it is separated the contents into 3 tables (There will be many tables). I need each of these tables in .dat file to be created as separate tables in the HTML file. How can I adjust my code to achieve this or please provide me some sample code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it carelessly - I'd suggest to allow Vim help you.

Here are the simple steps to convert your file to HTML:

1) install vim if it's not installed yet

2) open your .dat file

3) run the native Vim script which converts any text file to HTML format from Vim command mode (push "Escape" button to enter the command mode)

```
:runtime!syntax/2html.vim
```

4) you'll have new window with HTML-formatted text. Save this as a different file from Vim command mode.

```
:w test.html
```

5) If you want to convert files automatically through the shell script, you can use one custom function. But it makes so much overhead, so for automation I'd suggest to dive into awk.

```
vimhtml() { [[ -f "$1" ]] || return 1; vim +'syn on | run!syntax/2html.vim | wq | q' "$1";}
vimhtml try.dat
```

Here is what I've got after conversion. Don't worry about background, you can change this pretty simple.

[image]

Comment: I need this to be done through commands rather than user manually editing the file using vim editor. Any idea how I could do using command?

Comment: Modified my post appended 5th step to automate this. But it opens vim every time when you convert to HTML, so it's going to create some more overhead. Be careful.